# How to hook SetValue(String) in Xposed module

Tags: java, android, xposed-framework

In my app I want to hook SetValue(String) from TextEdit I tried code like this but no luck.

```
public class XposedClass implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {

        String classToHook = "android.widget.EditText";
        String functionToHook = "setValue";

        if(lpparam.packageName.equals("my.com.app")) {

           XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);

           findAndHookMethod(classToHook, lpparam.classLoader, functionToHook, String.class,
                   new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

                    XposedBridge.log("hooking: " + param.args[0]);

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows whats wrong with hook code above ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no function with following definition in the Android API[0].

```
android.widget.EditText.setValue(String)
```

So, basically you are hooking wrong function. May be you wanted to hook `android.widget.EditText.setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType)`

Moreover you can check the Xposed logs to know hooking errors in your code. `NoSuchMethodException` would be thrown when you will try to hook wrong function.

[0] https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html